# Oracle SQL Developer import CSV where enclosure is optional and is inside string

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to import CSV in my Oracle Database using SQL Developer. There are 5 columns and 2 rows in my CSV:

```
1,,"a,b",c,xx
2,a,d,e "f",xx
```

When I select Left and Right Enclosure as ", then there is an error in the second row.

When I select Left and Right Enclosure as None, then there is an error in the first row.

Is there a way to import my source CSV without modifying it?

Answer (score 1):

There's none (as far as I can tell), because there's ambiguity regarding the same character (double quotes in your case). It is either *a)* or *b)*, can't be both.

Though, if there are really only two rows, insert them manually.

Comment: Thanks. It was just an example. I have several CSV files, some have hundreds of thousand rows (I can open and save them with Excel) and others have millions rows. What is the best way to modify my CSV with millions of rows to the desired format?

Comment: It's difficult to say. I don't know which is the "best" way to do that. **However**: maybe you don't have to do anything. Omit the "optionally enclosed" parameter (who cares that some values are enclosed into double quotes?) and use only COMMA as column delimiter. That should let you load data into the table.

Comment: Where I can omit the "optionally enclosed" parameter? I don't see this parameter in Data Import Wizard..

Comment: It is part of SQL*Loader's control file. In SQL Developer, just omit *enclosures* (see Jeff's screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

No way for me to add a pic comment, so adding an answer to augment Littlefoot's...

Simply do this -

[image]

Then after you've imported your data -

[image]

- if you don't want the quotes, strip them out with some UPDATES and REGEX.

Comment: I don't need quotes, but I need commas inside the string. "a, b" should be in one column. On the screenshot, you have 6 columns and I need only 5.  A comma can be inside any of the columns.

Comment: Then add quotes to everything, then use a delimiter

Comment: How can I add quotes to everything? Do you mean I should modify my CSV before import?

Comment: Yes, modify your csv